# Nested (double) row by row iteration of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, vectorization

Hi I am trying to find a vectorized (or more efficient) solution to an iteration problem, where the only solution I found requires row by row iteration of a DataFrame with multiple loops. The actual data file is huge, so my current solution is practically unfeasible. I included line profiler outputs at the very end, if you'd like to have a look. The real problem is quite complex, so I'll try to explain this with a simple example (took me quite a while to simplify it :)):

Assume we have an airport with two landing strips side by side. Each plane lands (arrival time), taxis on one of the landing strips for a while, then takes off (departure time). Everything is stored in a Pandas DataFrame, which is sorted by the arrival time, as follows (see **EDIT2** for a bigger dataset for testing) :

```
PLANE   STRIP   ARRIVAL   DEPARTURE
0       1       85.00     86.00
1       1       87.87     92.76
2       2       88.34     89.72
3       1       88.92     90.88
4       2       90.03     92.77
5       2       90.27     91.95
6       2       92.42     93.58
7       2       94.42     95.58
```

Looking for solutions to two cases:

**1.** Build a list of events where there are more than one plane present on a single strip at a time. Do not include subsets of events (e.g. do not show [3,4] if there is a valid [3,4,5] case). The list should store the indices of the actual DataFrame rows. See function findSingleEvents() for a solution for this case (runs around 5 ms).

**2.** Build a list of events where there is at least one plane on each strip at a time. Do not count subsets of an event, only record the event with maximum number of planes. (e.g. do not show [3,4] if there is a [3,4,5] case). Do not count events that fully occur on a single strip. The list should store the indices of the actual DataFrame rows. See function findMultiEvents() for a solution for this case (runs around 15 ms).

**Working Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from __future__ import division

data =  [{'PLANE':0, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':85.00, 'DEPARTURE':86.00},
         {'PLANE':1, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':87.87, 'DEPARTURE':92.76},
         {'PLANE':2, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':88.34, 'DEPARTURE':89.72},
         {'PLANE':3, 'STRIP':1, 'ARRIVAL':88.92, 'DEPARTURE':90.88},
         {'PLANE':4, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':90.03, 'DEPARTURE':92.77},
         {'PLANE':5, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':90.27, 'DEPARTURE':91.95},
         {'PLANE':6, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':92.42, 'DEPARTURE':93.58},
         {'PLANE':7, 'STRIP':2, 'ARRIVAL':94.42, 'DEPARTURE':95.58}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PLANE','STRIP','ARRIVAL','DEPARTURE'])

def findSingleEvents(df):
    events = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        #Create temporary dataframe for each main iteration
        dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
        if len(dfTemp)>1:
            #convert index values to integers from long
            current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
            #loop backwards to remove elements that do not comply
            for i in reversed(current_event):
                if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
                    current_event.remove(i)
            events.append(current_event)
    #remove duplicate events
    events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    return events

def findMultiEvents(df):
    events = []
    for row in df.itertuples():
        #Create temporary dataframe for each main iteration
        dfTemp = df[(row.DEPARTURE>df.ARRIVAL) & (row.ARRIVAL<df.DEPARTURE)]
        if len(dfTemp)>1:
            #convert index values to integers from long
            current_event = [int(v) for v in dfTemp.index.tolist()]
            #loop backwards to remove elements that do not comply
            for i in reversed(current_event):
                if (dfTemp.loc[i].ARRIVAL > dfTemp.DEPARTURE).any():
                    current_event.remove(i)
            #remove elements only on 1 strip
            if len(df.iloc[current_event].STRIP.unique()) > 1:
                events.append(current_event)
    #remove duplicate events
    events = map(list, set(map(tuple, events)))
    return events

print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==1])
print findSingleEvents(df[df.STRIP==2])
print findMultiEvents(df)
```

**Verified Output:**

```
[[1, 3]]
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Obviously, these are neither efficient nor elegant solutions. With the huge DataFrame I have, running this will probably take hours. I thought about a vectorized approach quite a while, but could not come up anything solid. Any pointers/help would be welcome! I am also open to Numpy/Cython/Numba based approches.

Thanks!

**PS:** If you wonder what I will do with the lists: I will assign an `EVENT` number to each `EVENT`, and build a separate database with merging the data above, and the `EVENT` numbers as a separate column, to be used for something else. For Case 1, it will look something like this:

```
EVENT    PLANE   STRIP   ARRIVAL   DEPARTURE
0        4       2       90.03     92.77
0        5       2       90.27     91.95
1        5       2       90.27     91.95
1        6       2       92.42     95.58
```

**EDIT:** Revised the code and the test data set.

**EDIT2:** Use the code below to generate a 1000 row (or more) long DataFrame for testing purposes. (per @ImportanceOfBeingErnest 's recommendation)

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =  []
for i in range(1000):
    arrival = random.uniform(0,1000)
    departure = arrival + random.uniform(2.0, 10.0)
    data.append({'PLANE':i, 'STRIP':random.randint(1, 2),'ARRIVAL':arrival,'DEPARTURE':departure})

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PLANE','STRIP','ARRIVAL','DEPARTURE'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['ARRIVAL'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.PLANE  = df.index
```

**EDIT3:**

Modified version of the accepted answer. The accepted answer was not able to remove subsets of events. Modified version satisfies the rule "(e.g. do not show [3,4] if there is a valid [3,4,5] case)"

```
def maximal_subsets_modified(sets):
    sets.sort()
    maximal_sets = []
    s0 = frozenset()
    for s in sets:
        if not (s > s0) and len(s0) > 1:
            not_in_list = True
            for x in maximal_sets:
                if set(x).issubset(set(s0)):
                    maximal_sets.remove(x)
                if set(s0).issubset(set(x)):
                    not_in_list = False
            if not_in_list:
                maximal_sets.append(list(s0))
        s0 = s
    if len(s0) > 1:
        not_in_list = True
        for x in maximal_sets:
            if set(x).issubset(set(s0)):
                maximal_sets.remove(x)
            if set(s0).issubset(set(x)):
                not_in_list = False
        if not_in_list:
            maximal_sets.append(list(s0))
    return maximal_sets

def maximal_subsets_2_modified(sets, d):
    sets.sort()
    maximal_sets = []
    s0 = frozenset()
    for s in sets:
        if not (s > s0) and len(s0) > 1 and d.loc[list(s0), 'STRIP'].nunique() == 2:
            not_in_list = True
            for x in maximal_sets:
                if set(x).issubset(set(s0)):
                    maximal_sets.remove(x)
                if set(s0).issubset(set(x)):
                    not_in_list = False
            if not_in_list:
                maximal_sets.append(list(s0))
        s0 = s
    if len(s0) > 1 and d.loc[list(s), 'STRIP'].nunique() == 2:
        not_in_list = True
        for x in maximal_sets:
            if set(x).issubset(set(s0)):
                maximal_sets.remove(x)
            if set(s0).issubset(set(x)):
                not_in_list = False
        if not_in_list:
            maximal_sets.append(list(s0))
    return maximal_sets

# single

def hal_3_modified(d):
    sets = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda x: frozenset(d.PLANE.values[(d.PLANE.values <= x[0]) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x[2])]), 
        1, d.values
    )
    return maximal_subsets_modified(sets)

# multi

def hal_5_modified(d):
    sets = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda x: frozenset(d.PLANE.values[(d.PLANE.values <= x[0]) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x[2])]), 
        1, d.values
    )
    return maximal_subsets_2_modified(sets, d)
```

Comment: I would consider another data-structure if you are looking for efficiency, although, there are some real `pandas` wizards around here, and maybe they can suggest something performant in pandas

Comment: Note, you are using **the worst possible way** to iterate over a dataframe. Use `itertuples()`, iterating over indices and using `.loc` based indexing is going to be **super slow**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm well aware of the inefficiency :) I also looked at `itertuples()` and `iterrows()`, but I could not figure out how to implement the required nested loop.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga turns out my inefficient `iloc` based iteration is not setup correctly anyway. I need to fix that first.

Comment: in your actual dataset, what is `df.ARRIVAL.min()` & `df.ARRIVAL.max()`

Comment: They range from 0 to 7.7 million. They are seconds for a 3 month period, initialized to 0 seconds at the beginning of the data collection period.

Comment: How huge is "huge"? How many rows does the df have? How long is the longest time a plane can stay on a lane?

Comment: Also note that a simple python loop would solve the above example case in some 10 µs or so. Hence you should provide a test case with at least some 1000 elements or so to let people test against.

Comment: will the dataframe index equal `PLANE` always?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest agreed, "huge" is too ambiguous. Depending on the data file, I would say there may be up to 28 million rows. I would say the delta time (`DEPARTURE - ARRIVAL`) may vary between 2 and 20. I also agree with your recommendation to have a larger data set. I edited the post, and included a short bit of code to generate a DataFrame with 1000 rows (you may increase the parameters in the code for delta time) if you'd like.

Comment: @HaleemurAli Thanks for the code you put together! Yes, the dataframe index will be equal to `PLANE`. Also please see the edit for a random dataframe generator, to provide a bigger dataset per @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's recommendation. Also the code should run in Python 2.7.x, but that's my bad, not mentioning at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rewrote the solution using `DataFrame.apply` instead of iterating, and as optimization used numpy arrays wherever possible. I used `frozenset` because they are immutable and hashable and thus `Series.unique` works properly. `Series.unique` fails on elements of type `set`.

Also, I found `d.loc[list(x), 'STRIP'].nunique()` to be slightly faster than `d.loc[list(x)].STRIP.nunique()`. I'm not sure why, but I used the faster statement in the solution below.

### The algorithm in plain English:

For each row, create a set of indices lower than (or equals) the index of current index whose Departure is greater than the current Arrival. This results in a list of sets.

Return unique sets that are not subsets of other sets (and for the 2nd algorithm,  additionally filter that both `STRIP`s are referred to by the sets)

### (Update) 2nd Improvement:

1 small improvement is made by dropping down to the numpy layer and using `np.apply_along_axis` instead of using df.apply. This is possible 
since `PLANE` always equals the dataframe index and we can access the underlying matrix with `df.values`

I found a major improvement with the list comprehension that returns the maximal subsets

```
[list(x) for x in sets if ~np.any(sets > x)]
```

The above is an O(n^2) order operation. On small datasets this is very fast. However on bigger datasets this statement becomes the bottle neck. To optimize this, first sort the `sets`, and loop through the elements once more to find the maximal subsets. Once sorted, it is sufficient to check that elem[n] is not a subset of elem[n+1] to determine if elem[n] is a maximal subset. The sort procedure compares two elements with the `<` operation

### Timings:

While my original implementation improved the performance significantly in comparison to the OP's attempt, the algorithm was exponential-ordered, as the following chart shows.

I present only the timings for `findMultiEvents`, `hal_2` & `hal_5`. The relative performance of `findSinglEvents`, `hal_1` & `hal_3` are similarly comparable.

[image: algorithm execution time ~ input sizes]

scroll below to see the benchmarking code.

*note that I stopped benchmarking `findMumtiEvents` & `hal_2` earlier when it became evident that they were less efficient by an exponential factor*

### Implementation

---

#### Improved Implementation:

```
def maximal_subsets(sets):
    sets.sort()
    maximal_sets = []
    s0 = frozenset()
    for s in sets[::-1]:
        if s0 > s or len(s) < 2:
            continue
        maximal_sets.append(list(s))
        s0 = s
    return maximal_sets

def maximal_subsets_2(sets, d):
    sets.sort()
    maximal_sets = []
    s0 = frozenset()
    for s in sets[::-1]:
        if s0 > s or len(s) < 2 or d.loc[list(s), 'STRIP'].nunique() < 2:
            continue
        maximal_sets.append(list(s))
        s0 = s
    return maximal_sets

# single
def hal_3(d):
    sets = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda x: frozenset(d.PLANE.values[(d.PLANE.values <= x[0]) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x[2])]), 
        1, d.values
    )
    return maximal_subsets(sets)
# multi
def hal_5(d):
    sets = np.apply_along_axis(
        lambda x: frozenset(d.PLANE.values[(d.PLANE.values <= x[0]) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x[2])]), 
        1, d.values
    )
    return maximal_subsets_2(sets, d)
```

#### Original Implementation:

```
# findSingleEvents
def hal_1(d):
    sets = d.apply(
       lambda x: frozenset(
           d.index.values[(d.index.values <= x.name) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x.ARRIVAL)]
       ),
       axis=1
    ).unique()
    return [list(x) for x in sets if ~np.any(sets > x) and len(x) > 1]

# findMultiEvents
def hal_2(d):
    sets = d.apply(
        lambda x: frozenset(
            d.index.values[(d.index.values <= x.name) & (d.DEPARTURE.values > x.ARRIVAL)]
        ),
        axis=1
    ).unique()
    return [list(x) for x in sets 
            if ~np.any(sets > x) and
               len(x) > 1 and 
               d.loc[list(x), 'STRIP'].nunique() == 2]
```

#### Outputs:

The outputs are identical to the OP's implementation.

```
hal_1(df[df.STRIP==1])
[[1, 3]]
hal_1(df[df.STRIP==2])
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
hal_2(df)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
hal_3(df[df.STRIP==1])
[[1, 3]]
hal_3(df[df.STRIP==2])
[[4, 5], [4, 6]]
hal_5(df)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6]]
```

#### Test System Details:

```
os: windows 10
python: 3.6 (Anaconda)
pandas: 0.22.0
numpy: 1.14.3
```

### Benchmarking code:

---

```
import random

def mk_random_df(n):
    data =  []
    for i in range(n):
        arrival = random.uniform(0,1000)
        departure = arrival + random.uniform(2.0, 10.0)
        data.append({'PLANE':i, 'STRIP':random.randint(1, 2),'ARRIVAL':arrival,'DEPARTURE':departure})

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['PLANE','STRIP','ARRIVAL','DEPARTURE'])
    df = df.sort_values(by=['ARRIVAL'])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df.PLANE = df.index
    return df

dfs = {i: mk_random_df(100*(2**i)) for i in range(0, 10)}
times, times_2, times_5 = [], [], []

for i, v in dfs.items():
    if i < 5:
        t = %timeit -o -n 3 -r 3 findMultiEvents(v)
        times.append({'size(pow. of 2)': i, 'timings': t})

for i, v in dfs.items():
    t = %timeit -o -n 3 -r 3 hal_5(v)
    times_5.append({'size(pow. of 2)': i, 'timings': t})

for i, v in dfs.items():
    if i < 9:
        t = %timeit -o -n 3 -r 3 hal_2(v)
        times_2.append({'size(pow. of 2)': i, 'timings': t})
```

Comment: With the 1000 row dataframe, speed gains are more impressive. On my machine, around 50X for the single events case, and 17X for the multi events case.

Comment: i have made another improvement that improves performance as number of rows increases. will update when the benchmarks finish running.

Comment: @marillion, see updated answer for even faster solution

Comment: your production dataset should be processed in a few minutes with this update

Comment: This seems to be a great solution. Currently I am running my own benchmarks, and I will post the results. One thing to be careful here: it looks like the order of the columns in the DataFrame should precisely follow what I generated in the example df (`PLANE` `STRIP` `ARRIVAL` `DEPARTURE`). My actual data file has numerous other columns, and I had to sort them to make sure the first 4 columns match the example given in this post.

Comment: @marillion, the positional indexing was a small optimization. if you use the `sets = d.apply(...)` from the earlier implementation, there won't be much of a performance penalty.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time! This should be the accepted answer. I hope it was a good exercise for you as well.

Comment: just found out that your functions do not comply with the following requirement: *do not include subsets of events (e.g. do not show [3,4] if there is a valid [3,4,5] case)* . Both [3,4] and [3,4,5] are listed in the output from `hal_3` and `hal_5`. I tried fixing it, but haven't been able to do so yet.

Comment: there was a typo when i first copied the `maximal_subsets_2` function to the answer. use the current version of the code and try again.

Comment: I don't think it is about that. When I run my original functions and your updated functions for a random dataframe of 100 elements, the length of resulting lists are: 25, 42 vs. 27, 50 for single and multi cases. As mentioned, your functions include events such as [3,4] and [3,4,5] in the list at the same time, instead of only including [3,4,5].

Comment: I have posted a modified version of your code (see EDIT3), where the subset removal is implemented. It comes with a big hit to performance though.

Comment: @marillion, i'm travelling for the next few days, so it won't be possible for me to figure out what's wrong. but can you try this small example: `x = np.array([frozenset([]), frozenset([1]), frozenset([1,2]), frozenset([1,3]), frozenset([1,2,3])])` and then `maximal_subsets(x)` should return only `[1,2,3]`

Comment: @marillion, see updated answer for the bug fix. essentially, if the iteration is reversed, then any set that is a subset will be properly omitted from the final result

Comment: just realized you had posted an update. I tried your bug fix. I hate to say it, but it still does not work. If you are curious about what's going on, feel free to try the modified functions above (which double up the computation time), and compare the results using the random dataframe genarator provided above. I would never think this would be such a tricky question :)